# How to test facebook insights for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I completed all steps here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads/

... and installed the SDK properly in my app:

```
[FBSettings setDefaultAppID:@"xxxxx"];
[FBAppEvents activateApp];
```

I also added all necessary keys in the info.plist file.

My end goal is to run mobile app ads and measure CPI (cost per install), but I'm having trouble making the Insights work.

What I mean by that is that I run my app on my Device from XCode, but Insights is not showing any info. According to the insights docs, the **application_mobile_app_installs** info is updated about once every 15 minutes.

My question - how should I properly test Insights before submitting an update for my app to the App Store?

Comment: did this get resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
[FBSettings setLoggingBehavior:[NSSet setWithObject:FBLoggingBehaviorAppEvents]];
```

To your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in the app delegate.

If the app is reporting correctly to the Facebook back end, it will tell you in the xcode console output. If there is a problem, or you don't see any communication you know that the app is not configured correctly.

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSettings/#FBLoggingBehaviorAppEvents

FB setup gets me every time...One thing I have found is that using [cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/?q=facebook-ios-sdk) makes setup a little easier.

Best of luck!